# Generate presence/absence and count dataframe, binned hourly by location and ID (all possible combinations) from timestamped occurrence data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe of timestamps when an individual animal (ID) is detected in specific locations. Here is a short example of the data (ordered by location then timestampUTC for clarity):

```
df <- read.table(text =
                   "timestampUTC    location    ID
                 '2017-10-11 04:57:16'  JB12    A69-1602-2429
                 '2017-10-11 04:58:25'  JB12    A69-1602-2429
                 '2017-10-11 04:59:08'  JB12    A69-1602-2429
                 '2017-10-11 05:00:01'  JB12    A69-1602-2429
                 '2017-10-11 05:03:04'  JB12    A69-1602-2429
                 '2017-10-11 05:04:38'  JB12    A69-1602-2429
                 '2017-10-11 04:56:20'  JB13    A69-1601-47280
                 '2017-10-11 04:57:44'  JB13    A69-1601-47280
                 '2017-10-11 04:59:00'  JB13    A69-1601-47280
                 '2017-10-11 04:59:56'  JB13    A69-1601-47280
                 '2017-10-11 05:01:16'  JB13    A69-1601-47280
                 '2017-10-11 05:02:20'  JB13    A69-1601-47280
                 '2017-10-11 05:02:56'  JB13    A69-1601-47280
                 '2017-10-11 05:03:34'  JB13    A69-1601-47280
                 '2017-10-11 05:08:29'  JB13    A69-1602-2429
                 '2017-10-11 04:56:43'  WBR A69-1602-2428
                 '2017-10-11 04:57:09'  WBR A69-1602-2425
                 '2017-10-11 04:58:11'  WBR A69-1602-2428
                 '2017-10-11 04:58:42'  WBR A69-1602-2425
                 '2017-10-11 04:59:34'  WBR A69-1602-2428
                 '2017-10-11 05:00:13'  WBR A69-1602-2425
                 '2017-10-11 05:00:47'  WBR A69-1602-2428
                 '2017-10-11 05:01:39'  WBR A69-1602-2428
                 '2017-10-11 05:01:43'  WBR A69-1602-2425
                 '2017-10-11 05:02:49'  WBR A69-1602-2428
                 '2017-10-11 05:03:36'  WBR A69-1602-2428
                 '2017-10-11 05:04:38'  WBR A69-1602-2428
                 '2017-10-11 05:07:32'  WBR A69-1602-2428", header = T)
```

I want to generate a dataframe from these data where for every hourly bin and every location and every ID I have a column with whether that ID was present (1) or absent (0) in that location in that hour, and a column with the count of observations for that ID in that location in that hour. In slightly different wording - for every ID, I want to know whether it is present(1) or absent (0) and the count of observations for every hourly bin of the study period in every location.

For example, the data above has 4 unique IDs, 3 unique locations and observations that fall into two hourly bins (2017-10-11 04:00:00, 2017-10-11 05:00:00). The output would be a df with 24 lines (4 IDs x 3 locations x 2 hourly bins). The output should look something like this:

```
output <- read.table(text =
                   "HourlyBinUTC    location    ID  count   present
                 '2017-10-11 04:00:00'  JB13    A69-1601-47280  4   1
                 '2017-10-11 04:00:00'  JB13    A69-1602-2429   0   0
                 '2017-10-11 04:00:00'  JB13    A69-1602-2428   0   0
                 '2017-10-11 04:00:00'  JB13    A69-1602-2425   0   0
                 '2017-10-11 04:00:00'  JB12    A69-1601-47280  0   0
                 '2017-10-11 04:00:00'  JB12    A69-1602-2429   4   1
                 '2017-10-11 04:00:00'  JB12    A69-1602-2428   0   0
                 '2017-10-11 04:00:00'  JB12    A69-1602-2425   0   0
                 '2017-10-11 04:00:00'  WBR A69-1601-47280  0   0
                 '2017-10-11 04:00:00'  WBR A69-1602-2429   0   0
                 '2017-10-11 04:00:00'  WBR A69-1602-2428   3   1
                 '2017-10-11 04:00:00'  WBR A69-1602-2425   2   1
                 '2017-10-11 05:00:00'  JB13    A69-1601-47280  4   1
                 '2017-10-11 05:00:00'  JB13    A69-1602-2429   1   1
                 '2017-10-11 05:00:00'  JB13    A69-1602-2428   0   0
                 '2017-10-11 05:00:00'  JB13    A69-1602-2425   0   0
                 '2017-10-11 05:00:00'  JB12    A69-1601-47280  0   0
                 '2017-10-11 05:00:00'  JB12    A69-1602-2429   3   1
                 '2017-10-11 05:00:00'  JB12    A69-1602-2428   0   0
                 '2017-10-11 05:00:00'  JB12    A69-1602-2425   0   0
                 '2017-10-11 05:00:00'  WBR A69-1601-47280  0   0
                 '2017-10-11 05:00:00'  WBR A69-1602-2429   0   0
                 '2017-10-11 05:00:00'  WBR A69-1602-2428   6   1
                 '2017-10-11 05:00:00'  WBR A69-1602-2425   2   1", header = T)
```

*(in my real df which spans 19,887 hourly bins with 17 individuals and 4 locations I'd expect the output to have 1,352,316 lines)*

I am an R novice and have played around with reshape() and dcast() but am not familiar enough with the arguments to get what I need. I suspect this will be a job for the tidyverse - which I (clearly) desperately need to learn!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need any packages for that. I read in your `df`, but set option `stringsAsFactors`.

```
df <- read.table(text =
                 "timestampUTC    location    ID
                 '2017-10-11 04:57:16'  JB12    A69-1602-2429
                 ## ...
                 '2017-10-11 05:07:32'  WBR A69-1602-2428",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now, tell R that the first column is a timestamp, and then round the timestamp.

```
df[["timestampUTC"]] <- as.POSIXct(df[["timestampUTC"]], tz = "UTC")
df[["timestampUTC"]] <- trunc(df[["timestampUTC"]], "hours")
```

Then call `table` and transform the result into a data frame.

```
result <- as.data.frame(table(df))

##           timestampUTC location             ID Freq
## 1  2017-10-11 04:00:00     JB12 A69-1601-47280    0
## 2  2017-10-11 05:00:00     JB12 A69-1601-47280    0
## 3  2017-10-11 04:00:00     JB13 A69-1601-47280    4
## 4  2017-10-11 05:00:00     JB13 A69-1601-47280    4
## 5  2017-10-11 04:00:00      WBR A69-1601-47280    0
## 6  2017-10-11 05:00:00      WBR A69-1601-47280    0
## 7  2017-10-11 04:00:00     JB12  A69-1602-2425    0
## 8  2017-10-11 05:00:00     JB12  A69-1602-2425    0
## 9  2017-10-11 04:00:00     JB13  A69-1602-2425    0
## 10 2017-10-11 05:00:00     JB13  A69-1602-2425    0
## 11 2017-10-11 04:00:00      WBR  A69-1602-2425    2
## 12 2017-10-11 05:00:00      WBR  A69-1602-2425    2
## 13 2017-10-11 04:00:00     JB12  A69-1602-2428    0
## 14 2017-10-11 05:00:00     JB12  A69-1602-2428    0
## 15 2017-10-11 04:00:00     JB13  A69-1602-2428    0
## 16 2017-10-11 05:00:00     JB13  A69-1602-2428    0
## 17 2017-10-11 04:00:00      WBR  A69-1602-2428    3
## 18 2017-10-11 05:00:00      WBR  A69-1602-2428    6
## 19 2017-10-11 04:00:00     JB12  A69-1602-2429    3
## 20 2017-10-11 05:00:00     JB12  A69-1602-2429    3
## 21 2017-10-11 04:00:00     JB13  A69-1602-2429    0
## 22 2017-10-11 05:00:00     JB13  A69-1602-2429    1
## 23 2017-10-11 04:00:00      WBR  A69-1602-2429    0
## 24 2017-10-11 05:00:00      WBR  A69-1602-2429    0
```

If you want to include an `ID`, say, that never showed up in the data, 
you need to tell `table` what values for `ID` are possible. You can do so by making `ID` a factor.

```
df[["ID"]] <- factor(df[["ID"]],
                     levels = c("A69-1602-2429", "A69-1601-47280",
                                "A69-1602-2428", "A69-1602-2425",
                                "foo"))
```

Or for additional hours:

```
df[["timestampUTC"]] <-
    factor(df[["timestampUTC"]],
           levels =
               seq(from = as.POSIXct("2017-10-01 00:00:00", tz = "UTC"),
                   to   = as.POSIXct("2017-10-03 00:00:00", tz = "UTC"),
                   by   = "1 hour"))
```

The results would then include zero counts.

```
## ...
## 25 2017-10-11 04:00:00     JB12            foo    0
## 26 2017-10-11 05:00:00     JB12            foo    0
## 27 2017-10-11 04:00:00     JB13            foo    0
## 28 2017-10-11 05:00:00     JB13            foo    0
## 29 2017-10-11 04:00:00      WBR            foo    0
## 30 2017-10-11 05:00:00      WBR            foo    0
```

Instead of a zero-one variable for `present`, I'd suggest a logical vector:

```
present <- result$Freq > 0
cbind(result, present)

##           timestampUTC location             ID Freq present
## 1  2017-10-11 04:00:00     JB12 A69-1601-47280    0   FALSE
## 2  2017-10-11 05:00:00     JB12 A69-1601-47280    0   FALSE
## 3  2017-10-11 04:00:00     JB13 A69-1601-47280    4    TRUE
## 4  2017-10-11 05:00:00     JB13 A69-1601-47280    4    TRUE
## 5  2017-10-11 04:00:00      WBR A69-1601-47280    0   FALSE
## ...
```

Comment: Thanks @EnricoSchumann but this only does part of what I need. I want the resulting df to have every possible combination of hourly bin, location and ID so even if no ID was seen in a location in a certian hour I still want there to be a line for every ID (the frequency and presence will just be 0 for ech of them) I hope that makes sense.

Comment: This should happen automatically as long as every ID, hour and location shows up at least once (no matter in what combination). If that is not the case, you can define factor levels for a variable; I have added an example to the answer.

Comment: Oh, yes I see now @EnricoSchumann. I don't think I made this clear in the original post, but I want the output to have hour bins for every hour from the first in the dataset to the last. The solution you have given only gives hour bins where at least one ID was detected at least one location. Obviously, the rest of the hour bins aren't there because no IDs were detected in any location, so how can we fill in these gaps?

Comment: See the example I had added to the answer: make the column a `factor` and specify levels. I added another example for the timestamp.

Comment: Perfect - thank you @EnricoSchumann! I figured it would be the same as using factor to specify ID levels but wasn't sure how to do this without typing out each time bin. Thanks for putting up with my noviceship.